# Replace Child giving error (failed to execute "replacechild" on node)?

Tags: javascript, replace, parent-child, getelementbyid

I hope everyone is doing well

I was using replacechild when i faced this error:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be replaced is not a child of this node.

But i see the code is okay and i can't find any issue with it

Here is the code:

Javascript code:

```
let list = document.getElementById("List");
list.replaceChild(text2, document.getElementById("last"));
```

HTML Code:

```html
<ol id="List">
  <li><div class="child" id="first">Child 1</div></li>
  <li><div class="child" id="Second">Child 2</div></li>
  <li><div class="child">Child 3</div></li>
  <li><div class="child" id="last">Child 4</div></li>
</ol>
```

Text with which i am replacing child with:

```
let text2 = document.createTextNode("This is a heading");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element with `id = "last"` is not a child of the element with `id = "List"`. Note that there is a `li` element between them.
According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild), the replaced element must be directly child.
Example below:

```js
const text = document.createTextNode("This is a heading");
const list = document.getElementById("list");
const selectedNode = document.getElementById("last");
selectedNode.parentElement.replaceChild(text, selectedNode);
```

```html
<ol id="list">
  <li><div class="child" id="first">Child 1</div></li>
  <li><div class="child" id="Second">Child 2</div></li>
  <li><div class="child">Child 3</div></li>
  <li><div class="child" id="last">Child 4</div></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks 
It worked
So this same rule also apply on removechild, right?

Comment: @BehindTheWebPage, Methods such as removeChild, replaceChild, appendChild and etc. work only in the "parentNode <-> childNode" scheme. This is perfectly described in the (MDN documentation)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node#methods]. If you are just learning a language, I recommend reading [this public tutorial](https://javascript.info) ([link to github repository](https://github.com/javascript-tutorial)). Specifically in [this section](https://javascript.info/dom-navigation) you can read about moving through the DOM model.
I was glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The <div> element with id="last" is not a child of element with id "list". It is a child of last <li> element.

The second problem is that allowed children for <ol> are only <li>.
You can not replace it with a text node.

If you want to simply change a text of the last li, you should use something like.

```
document.getElementById("last").innerHTML = "This is a heading";
```

but that will not make it a heading, just a change of text.
In my opinion you should study more about html and DOM to understand these concepts.

Comment: Thanks @Nikes
Can YOU share some resources where i can learn more about these?
As i have just started yet learning Javascript and Html

Comment: sure thing @BehindTheWebPage
One of great tools is https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp
you will find there step by step tutorials and also "Try it yourself" prepared resources for every step.